Trusted signing taking longer then expected from Onprem..earlier tested was taking 1-2 sec for 1 file but now taking 8sec
I have query regarding trusted signing service from  onprem VM .We initially tested code signed using trusted signing 1-2 sec per file 2 weeks back but today seeing longer time of 8sec for signing 1 file. Any idea what would be causing this delay.
Use case- onprem virtual machines ---> using azure Trusted signing
for 1000 file i was expecting 30 mins but took 90 mins.

Sometimes network latency does play a factor, where your build machines are vs the endpoint you are reaching out to send your signing requests.
